# IOS Voice Recognition / Control

Tags: ios, xcode, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

First of all, I know there are other threads similar to this, but in fairness, I really do not think they are the same.

Okay, so I really need some help. I am an experienced programmer, however, I am just learning to code IOS apps on Xcode. I am trying to make an app where when you say "cheese" a photo will be taken automatically (I know genius).

Most threads or answers I see are talking about text-->speech or vice versa. Additionally, I've seen some answers that don't specifically address my question.

Can someone please share with me how I can code (presumably with sfspeechrecognizer) a simple app where when a say a word an action is performed.

For example:

When the word "apple" is recognized, a function is called.

Thank you!

PS: Also please share actually code so that I can better understand